# Disable or grey out a node in the TreeNode Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview, visibility

How do I disable a specific node so the user can not select it. Hiding it for the user is also valid.

I tried the Visible property but that hides the entire tree (all nodes). I only want a few of the nodes disabled/hidden.

C# using Visual Studio 2005 TreeNode Editor.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `TreeNode` itself does not have any `Enabled` property, so you will need to find some means of tracking that state. One way to do this is to create a new class that inherits `TreeNode` and that features an `Enabled` property. Another way is to maintain a list of disabled tree nodes.

Once that is done, you can use the [`ForeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.forecolor.aspx) property of the `TreeNode` to have it appear grayed out (for instance using the [`SystemColors.GrayText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.graytext.aspx) value).

Finally you can use the [`BeforeSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect.aspx) event to evaluate whether it's OK for the user to select a particular node, and use the `Cancel` property of the event args in that event to prevent selecting it if that node is disabled:

```
private void TreeView_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !NodeIsEnabled(e.Node);
}
```

Comment: If you also want to Disable the Checkbox use *_BeforeCheck

Answer (score 13):

I just found another way to handle the disabled treenodes. If you gray in the treenodes you don't want to use, you can ask for the color and not allow all grayed nodes.

```
    private void TreeView_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(SystemColors.GrayText==e.Node.ForeColor)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: Of course, if you are using the CheckBox attribute, you need to also handle the BeforeCheck event:        private void TreeView_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SystemColors.GrayText == e.Node.ForeColor)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Add and remove the nodes on the fly.
2. Owner draw and handle the clicks and send it to another node.

Answer (score -2):

set disabled node by `yourNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None`

I think you need also disable expandable this node 
`yourNode.PopulateOnDemand = false`

Comment: TreeNodeSelectAction is in System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace. Question is about Windows Forms. Cheers